# Dynamically adding marker to Google Maps [Android]

Tags: android, maps, marker

I have an issue when trying to add a marker dynamically to my google maps. The error I get is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    mapView = (MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.map);

    if (mapView != null) {
        mapView.onCreate(null);
        mapView.onResume();
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    this.map = googleMap;
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
}


public void populatePositions(final String jsonString) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("location");
                    JSONObject object;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String member = object.getString("member").toString();
                        String longitude = object.getString("longitude").toString();
                        String latitude = object.getString("latitude").toString();
                        addMarker(member, Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    });
    t.start();
}


public void addMarker(String name, double latitude, double longitude){
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(name));
}
```

This is the code I have. The map is initialized in OnMapReady, but when the server sends a location to add, It crashes due to map not being initialized.

Comment: where are you calling populatePositions?

Comment: I have a controller class that retrieves the message from the server, and the message is then sent to the populatePositions method. I retrieve the message from the controller class, however when I call the addMarker method, map is null.

Comment: after calling getMapAsync yout should wait for onMapReady and than you allowed to work with your map pbject

Comment: so when controller calls server?

Comment: On button click I register a user with name and the position of the user. The server sends a jsonarray of the users connected to the server each 15-20 seconds. When the server returns a JsonObject that contains the locations of the users, I send it to the populatePositions method in a Fragment. Everything works fine, I can log and retrieve the users fine, but once I call the addMarker method, i get the nullpointerexception.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMirzaei how would you go about doing that?

Comment: @E.AD Before calling populatePositaion you can check your map state and if mapReady was called than you call your method else you can cash the string in some variable and in your onMapReady you can check cash and if it wasn&amp;#39;t null call your populatePositaion method with cashed variable and set the cash to null